# Efficient CSS selector

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

I know we should avoid using CSS descendant selectors but I was just wondering which of these two is more efficient and why ?

```
#myDiv .childDiv .grandchildAnchor span
```

or

```
#myDiv > .childDiv > .grandchildAnchor > span
```

You can assume both are valid for my markup. How should I test for such kind of things. Is there an online platform where I can write both versions of my code and it will fetch me results in terms of efficiency.

EDIT: I want to learn these things.

- Given two CSS selectors how would I know which of them work faster. Just for knowledge.
- Online platform where I can test the rendering of two selectors.

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where the difference would be even measurable.

Comment: Imagine a situation where I replace all my selectors similar to V1 with the selectors in v2 wherever possible. I have long CSS file. I just want to know how browser will read them and parse more efficiently.

Comment: @blunderboy - When you say long is it a few hundreds K? AKA nothing.

Comment: Both selectors are terrible, use the selector that correctly describes the elements desired, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is performance tester
https://sites.google.com/site/skiadocs/developer-documentation/skia-debugger
example of use
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/css-paint-times/

Answer (score 4):

If you're planning your CSS selectors around which ones are more efficient, you're focusing on the wrong issue.

Don't be penny wise and pound foolish.

It takes an absolutely massive amount of HTML and CSS to slow down a browser in any meaningful way, so rather than focusing on which selector is more efficient, focus on which selector is appropriate. You'll save more in performance by compressing your images, minifying your CSS and JS, or simply removing a *single* image from the page.

In your example, neither selector is appropriate and neither is efficient. Unless you have a *very* good reason to nest selections, your CSS should be optimized to be:

```
//specificity 0-0-1-0
.some-span-type {
    ...
}
```

It's possible that you may need to check if the span is in a particular type of container, in which case you might want to use:

```
//specificity 0-0-2-0
.some-container .some-span-type {
    ...
}
```

It's also possible that you may need to check if the span is within a unique container, in which case you might want to use:

```
//specificity 0-1-1-0
#some-container .some-span-type {
    ...
}
```

The issue is that once you start adding more styles with two or three selectors, you'll quickly find that you'll need three or four or five selectors to style subsequent elements to properly override the existing styles.

Comment: I already mentioned in my question that I know we should not use nested selectors. I just wanted to know which of these work better and why. Given two selectors, how should I know which of them is better. So I asked of an online platform. Anyways, thanks for your answer.

Comment: `.foo .bar` is meant for when you want to select all `.bar` descendants of `.foo`, and `.foo > .bar` is when you want to select all `.bar` *children* of `.foo`. There is a meaningful difference, and your question is similar to asking, "Which performs better, a hammer or a screwdriver?"

Comment: I see your point and I understand the difference. But suppose there is only one element with class bar inside my element with class foo. Then  both are equivalent. Right ? Now, there is no question of hammer / screwdriver because both are same in my case.

Comment: In that case, you should stick with `.bar`.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mozilla there is a clear-cut answer: **Avoid the descendant selector**

> The descendant selector is the most expensive selector in CSS. It is
> dreadfully expensive—especially if the selector is in the Tag or
> Universal Category.
>
> Frequently, what is really desired is the child selector.  For
> instance, the performances are so bad, that descendant selectors are
> banned in Firefox' User Interface CSS, without a specific
> justification. It's a good idea to do the same on your Web pages
>
> **BAD**
> treehead treerow treecell {…}
>
> **BETTER, BUT STILL BAD** (see next guideline)
> treehead > treerow > treecell {…}

You can find the above quote and more at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ids`. Then you can have the benefit in automated testing see QTP